# Get dependency tree of a particular package in python

Tags: python, pip

I want to get dependencies of a particular package. Using below command I get the complete dependency tree showing all the installed libraries.

> pipdeptree --json-tree -p numpy

Is there a way to get only the dependencies of a package in tree form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the help in `pipdeptree -h`, the `--json-tree` option overrides the `-p` option:

```
--json-tree       Display dependency tree as json which is nested the
                  same way as the plain text output printed by default.
                  This option overrides all other options (except
                  --json).
```

So, unfortunately, it looks like showing the tree of a single package as json is not normally possible. Using just the `-p` option without `--json-tree` works as expected:

```
$ pipdeptree -p numpy
numpy==1.16.2
```

But unfortunately that is just regular output.

Of course you could always hack it together by importing pipdeptree into a script:

```
import pipdeptree
import json

pkgs = pipdeptree.get_installed_distributions()
dist_index = pipdeptree.build_dist_index(pkgs)
tree = pipdeptree.construct_tree(dist_index)
json_tree = json.loads(pipdeptree.render_json_tree(tree, indent=0))
print([package for package in json_tree if package['package_name'] == 'numpy'][0])
```

outputs

```
{'required_version': '1.16.2', 'dependencies': [], 'package_name': 'numpy', 'installed_version': '1.16.2', 'key': 'numpy'}
```

The source code is here if you want to try something like this: https://github.com/naiquevin/pipdeptree/blob/master/pipdeptree.py

Comment: Thanks! Even I thought to do the same but its kind of time consuming to find the package in the tree and getting dependencies if we are looking for large no. of package versions.